# Folder being published even after setting to not copy

Tags: asp.net-core

I am having a problem with deleting folders at the time of publishing my project via FTP to the server. Even using the code below, the `upload` folder is still sent and the solutions I found on the internet did not solve.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\upload">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

**My FTP publishing configuration:**
[image]

**Publishing log:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this?

<CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>

Comment: @PramilGawande I tried it now and it didn't work either: https://prnt.sc/t85jqh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `**\*.*` if you want to exclude everything under that folder:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\upload\**\*.*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/7861